Why did my ceiling fan that I just added a remote to quit spinning when I turned it on
Added a remote control to a ceiling fan w/ light fixture. When I turn on the fan with remote control the light fixture begins to rotate as well! Then the fan made a strange sound and stopped spinning so I unplugged it from the wall. I can't rotate the blades in either direction. Any help is greatly appreciated!

You have mechanically assembled something wrong.  You may have ruined the fan.  The only way to asses the damage is to take things apart.

I followed the remote wiring diagram without any problems. Can you be more specific about what I should look for?Thank you.

If the light fixture rotates, that is a mechanical problem, whether your electrical connection is right or not. Disassemble, and reassemble with the fixture mounted with all the specified fasteners so it is unable to rotate.

so I unplugged it from the wall  .... how is the fan powered? ... it should not be connected to a wall outlet

sounds like you installed the fan assembly upside down ... the lights should not spin ... please add pictures to your post

This I gotta see. Please post a picture.

You put a screw or dropped a part where it doesn't belong when you put it back together so the fan is grabbing the light and turning it.  Hopefully it just ground to a stop and didn't break.
Remove power, take it down off the ceiling, figure out what is binding the light to the fan blades, and inspect for damage.  Have someone else do this if you're not experienced enough to know when you see something wrong
